Access environment variables in a config files which only contains config object
I'm using nest.js to build a very basic application with MikroOrm as my ORM.
I created a configuration file for the ORM config and i would like to use my environment variables within that config file. however, the environment variables are not being loaded to this file.
I've also tested one of my controllers and it seems like they are being loaded to "nest related" files but not regular TS files that are part of the application.
I'm sure that the solution will be ridiculously easy and obvious but i somehow missed it
I'm using the regular setup which is mentioned in the docs.
Environment variables setup docs
app.module.ts
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MikroOrmModule } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserService } from './modules/user/services/user.service';
import { InvoiceService } from './modules/invoice/services/invoice.service';
import { LineItemService } from './modules/line-item/services/line-item.service';
import { BillToService } from './modules/bill-to/services/bill-to.service';
import { BillFromService } from './modules/bill-from/services/bill-from.service';
import { config } from './configs/database.config';

// TODO: docker will be on the top layer

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MikroOrmModule.forRoot(config),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService, 
    UserService, 
    InvoiceService, 
    LineItemService, 
    BillToService, 
    BillFromService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

database.config.ts (ORM configuration file)
import { Migrator } from '@mikro-orm/migrations';
import { MySqlDriver } from '@mikro-orm/mysql';
import { BaseRepository } from 'src/libs/db/base-repository.repository';

console.log(process.env.DB_PASSWORD) // results in undefined value

export const config = {
    entities: ['./dist/core/entities'],
    entitiesTs: ['./src/core/entities/*.*'],
    dbName: 'invoice-app-be',
    driver: MySqlDriver,
    entityRepository: BaseRepository,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'mikro_orm_migrations',
      path: './lib/db/migrations/',
      allOrNothing: true,
    },
    extensions: [Migrator],
  };

